# Jquery Ajax click show page in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one question about jquery click to load url in a div using id.

I am trying when user clicking the `class="open" id="1"` then the ajax URL will open just `id="openpage1"` but the code showing in all `id="openpageXX"` what i am doing wrong here anyone can help me in this regard ?

```
$.base_url = 'http://localhost/';
$(".open").on('click', function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#openpage" + ID).slideToggle('fast');
    var URL = $.base_url + 'page.php';
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: URL,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        if (html) {
           $(".page_area").html(html);
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
```

Html

```
<!--First Post Started-->
<div class="post_area" id="1">
  <div class="open" id="1">Click for 1</div>
  <div class="opened_page" id="openpage1">
    When user click (class=open id 1 then ajax page will need to open just here)
  </div>
</div>
<!--First Post finished-->

<!--Second post started-->
<div class="post_area" id="2">
<div class="open" id="2">Click for 2</div>
  <div class="opened_page" id="openpage2">
    When user click (class=open id 2 then ajax page will need to open just here)
  </div>
</div>
<!--Second Post finished-->
```

Comment: the standard rule for ID is that in a page it should be unique. and ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 issues

1. I strongly suggest using unique non-numeric IDs - but my code no longer needs ID - I use datza-id to hold the information for the link
2. you need to find the closest opened_page - you try page_area which is not in your HTML
3. I would cache the clicked object to use in the success

like this:

```
<div class="post_area">
  <div class="open" data-id="1">Click to open</div>
  <div class="opened_page">
    When user click (class=open id 1 then ajax page will need to open just here)
  </div>
</div>
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $(".open").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // in chase you change to a link or button
     var $this = $(this),
           URL = $.base_url + 'page.php?page='+$this.data("id"),
         $page = $this.next("opened_page"); // sibling
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: URL,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html) {
         if (html) {
            $page.html(html).slideToggle('fast');; // sibling
         }
       }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dear. Can you tell me what is [1] in this code: `var ID = $this.attr("id").split("_")[1];`

Comment: but i have so may post in one page not just id 1. What should i do for it. Can you tell me ?

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. but it is not showing the `page.php` in `opened_page` div.

Comment: the page.php not have any connection like for example that page have just <img src="image url"> just this.

Comment: there is not have any error. When i click .open then it should show the page.php is in opened_page right but it is not showing.

Comment: So there are many more issues - spelling and www vs non-www cross domain stuff. The code will work when you have solved those